# Retrieve the maximum from alphanumeric values for a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
CREATE TABLE itemgroup
    ([itemid] varchar(13), [groupid] varchar(57))
;

INSERT INTO itemgroup
    ([itemid], [groupid])
VALUES
    ('Item1', 'Group1'),
    ('Item2', 'Group2'),
    ('Item3', 'Group1'),
    ('Item4', 'Group3'),
    ('Item5', 'Group2'),
    ('Item6', 'Group1'),
    ('Item7', 'Group3'),
    ('Item8', 'Group1')
;
```

I need to find the group with most items.

I was trying to do this:

```sql
SELECT itemgroup where (select MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(groupid),1)) from itemgroup);
```

It says substr() is not a built-in function. I was not doing in any database instead I was doing here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4a0e20/58

Could please someone see what's the issue? Whether my query is wrong or this won't work here on the above website?

Comment: What if there is a tie?  Based on the fiddle and the syntax, I added the SQL Server tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT top 1 count(*),[groupid] from itemgroup
group by [groupid]
order by count(*) desc
```

You must use Group by function and count (*)

OutPut looks like :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it

```
SELECT TOP 1 groupid FROM itemgroup GROUP BY GroupId ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

You appear to be using SQLServer; the function is called SUBSTRING, not SUBSTR. Also, your data appears not to need TRIMming, SUBSTRING(x, 1) is a non op, CAST needs an `as DATATYPE_HERE`, a WHERE clause must represent a boolean expression and you won't get much joy from a query that omits a FROM clause in this context